# Error in Downloading Jupiter Notebook from Github

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I normally use raw to download the .ipynb files from Github using a mac. However, lately, I encountered some .ipynb files that can only be saved as Archive or Web Scourse.  Any reason for this, please?

Comment: What happens when you try to clone or download the repo? Does it still come out wrong?

Comment: I can clone or fork the file without problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue in GitHub. See a workaround [here](https://github.com/mmcky/nyu-econ-370/issues/10)

I suggest you to use [mybinder](https://mybinder.org/) for having interactive notebooks.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful info!